# Get URI from Object

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I am using [ModernUI](https://mui.codeplex.com/) for developing a WPF application. It contains a control called **Link** which can be used for navigating through pages. It's also used in Tab controls for displaying pages on multiple tabs (Each tab serves as a link).

My requirement is to generate tabs dynamically but in each tab I have to display same content (same user control).

The only way to **set the Link content** is through `Source` property which accepts an object of Type `URI`.

Suppose if I create 5 tabs (5 links) and set the same URI for each tab then the `UserControl` object is shared among tabs.(If I make change on 1 tab it reflects on all the other tabs).

How should I prevent this? Is there a way I can use a Runtime object as an URI?

Any suggestions are welcome if it can be done using some alternate approach?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed have five different tabs, you are supposed, by design, to use five different sources. If you want to have the same content initially, you should create five different instances of `Uri` type object corresponding to five `Link`s.

In addition to that, you'll also have to make sure that all the `Uri`s don't point to the same thing. If they do, change in that same thing will be reflected across all those tabs.

Comment: Yeah, identified that issue by myself.
Finally modified the system tab control to meet my requirements.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You should either post your own solution and accept the answer or accept one of the existing answers - so that others know what the solution is!

Comment: Please give me some time. Still working on it.
Will post it as soon as I complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **TabItem Template** I modified for my cause. Hope it would be beneficial for someone else as well....

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI">

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabControlNormalBorderBrush" Color="#8C8E94"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EAF6FD" Offset="0.15"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#D9F0FC" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#BEE6FD" Offset=".5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#A7D9F5" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemSelectedBackground" Color="#F9F9F9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemHotBorderBrush" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" Opacity="0.1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBackground" Color="#F4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItemDisabledBorderBrush" Color="#FFC9C7BA"/>
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label x:Name="LblCon" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontSize="18"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="Overlay" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"  Opacity="0.1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"></Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Overlay" Value="{DynamicResource Accent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource Accent}"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" TargetName="LblCon" Value="18"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" TargetName="LblCon" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Overlay" Value="{DynamicResource Accent}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="LblCon" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="LblCon" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="LblCon" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="LblCon" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource TabItemDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```